# How to select from database according to current time

Tags: php, sql

I am making a school portal system and right now I am  making the page for students to view homework. I want their homework to be highlighted in red, or not shown at all if the current date is past the due date. How can I do this? 
My code for the page

```
<?php
//including the database connection file
include_once("connection.php");
    $id= $_GET['id'];


//fetching data in descending order (lastest entry first)
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM homework where class_id= '$id'"); 

?>

<html>
<head>    
    <title>View IS</title>
</head>

<body>

    <table width='80%' border=0>
        <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
            <td>Task</td>
            <td>Date Set </td>
            <td>Date Due </td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        //while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {         
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$res['description']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$res['dateset']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$res['datedue']."</td>";

        }
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
```

Database: [image: database]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `query`, use a `prepared statement` with `bind_param` which is much safer. Then just compare the dates to check if `$res['datedue']` passed or not. This should be it:

```
<?php
    include_once("connection.php"); //including the database connection file
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');    //set the default time zone to your time zone (this is just an example)
    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM homework WHERE class_id=?");
    $result->bind_param("i", (int)$_GET['id']);
    $result->execute();
    $result2 = $result->get_result();
?>
<html>
<head>    
    <title>View IS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width='80%' border=0>
        <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
            <td>Task</td>
            <td>Date Set </td>
            <td>Date Due </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            while($res = $result2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {   
                if (date("Y-m-d") > $res['datedue']) {
                    echo "<tr style=\"color: red;\">";
                        echo "<td>".$res['description']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$res['dateset']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$res['datedue']."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                } else {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>".$res['description']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$res['dateset']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$res['datedue']."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
```

You could also use `$time = new DateTime;` and then `$time->format("Y-m-d")` instead of `date("Y-m-d")`.

[More about time zones.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: Does it matter in this case?

Comment: I usually do it with `strtotime` but looks like it is unnecessary here, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Dharman Thanks again, I've updated my answer. I don't deal with date comparisons that often.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, could you pleas explain this line:                                   $result->bind_param("i", (int)$_GET['id']);

Comment: `$result->bind_param("i", (int)$_GET['id']);` - Here we insert the data into the prepared statement (`$result`). `"i"` is the type of data we're inserting, in this case an `integer` (a number), and here `(int)$_GET['id']` were casting `$_GET['id']` into an `integer` (a number). Casting is converting a data type into another data type. You can learn more about casting here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.cast.php.

Answer (score 2):

You should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries.

I have used the date function to compare the dates if the date is greater then I've put some style while in else there is no style. I have gave you the idea now you can modify accordingly.

```
    <table width='80%' border=0>
            <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
                <td>Task</td>
                <td>Date Set </td>
                <td>Date Due </td>
            </tr>
            <?php 
            //while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    $current_date=date("Y-m-d");
            while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 


            if($current_date > $res['datedue'] ){

?>
<tr style='color:red;'>;
<?php

    }else {
    <tr>
    }

                echo "<td>".$res['description']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$res['dateset']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$res['datedue']."</td>";
    </tr>
            }
            ?>
        </table>
```

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp)

Comment: You can't compare dates using strings. Need to convert them to timestamps or use DateTime object.

Comment: @triby Why not? If the dates are iso 8601 format you can.

Answer (score 1):

## Don`t use concated raw SQL.

Use variable binding to prevent SQL injections.

```
<?php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM homework where class_id= ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', (int)$_GET['id']); // bind vairable and cast it to integer (it is a good practice when you get data from outside)
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($res = $result->fetch()){
  // Your code here
  var_dump($res);
}
```

I will suggest using `PDO` instead of `mysqli`. You can read more about SQL Injections here: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

## Don't use `select *`  (wildcard)

```
SELECT description, dateset, datedue, datedue < NOW() AS is_expired FROM homework where class_id= ?
```

Check the value of `is_expired` to see which results you will mark in red

---

*I haven't tried the code but I guess it will work as expected*

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: You are mixing APIs. MySQLi and PDO are different.